# Substituting a character with a string from a string array in java

Tags: java

Hello to all coders out there, any help is appreciated for this is a personal project and not for a school that I thought would be fun, but not turning out to be so. Now the project is to read in an input file, the compare it to a srting[] alphabets = {"a","b","c"...."z"} then to replace the alphabets with another string[] newAlphabets = {"Apple", "Ball", "Cat", .... "Zebra"}. Now I have tried the simple replaceAll() example and it kinda worked. But the plan is to input a .txt file and have the substitution run and output with a new file.
**JamesBond.txt**: Name is Bond, James Bond.
**Output.txt** should be: NoAppleMonkeyElephant InsectSnake BallOpenNoDuck, JungelAppleMonkeyElephantSnake BallOpenNoDuck.
*Here's what I have so far:*

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FnR {
// array of alphabets 
static String[] alphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
        "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
        "v","w","x","y","z"};
 // replace the alphabets with substituted string
 static String[] newAlphabets = 
{"Apple","Bat","Cat","Dog","Egale","Fox","Goat","Horse","Insect","Jungle",
"King","Lion","Monkey","Nose","Open","Push","Quit","Run","Stop","Turn",
 "Up","Volume","Water","X-mas","Yes","Zip"};
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
 public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
    try {
        //reads in the file 
        Scanner input = new Scanner("JamesBond.txt");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            //prints the txt file out
            System.out.println(line);
            // replaces the letter j with Jungel in the text regardless of 
        case
            String newtxt1 = line.replaceAll("J","Jungle");

            //prints new text 
            System.out.println(newtxt1);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}   }
Output:
Name is Bond, James Bond
Name is Bond, Jungleames Bond
```

Comment: Very sorry about that, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to give you the code. This answer is providing hints for you to write the code yourself.

Don't use [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). You'd have to do it 26 times, and that is not really a good solution.

Instead, create a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for building up the result string. Then loop through the characters of the input string with a normal `for` loop using String methods [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) and [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Now here is the main "trick" that will simplify your code. Java stores text in Unicode, where letters `a` to `z` are stored consecutively. That means you can *calculate* the index into your `newAlphabets` array. To do that, you'll write code like this:

```
char ch = ...;
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    int idx = ch - 'a';  // number between 0 and 25, inclusive
    // use idx here
} else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
    int idx = ch - 'A';  // number between 0 and 25, inclusive
    // use idx here
} else {
    // not a letter
}
```

Hope this helps you write the code yourself.

Comment: Oops! Typo fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Andreas I will try to work it out like you suggested and get back to you guys. So any help or suggestion in the future is appreciated.